# React-js duplicate props issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I have a show page that display ticket details including its comments and this page has a simple form to create comments under this ticket.
the form submitted and add comment successfully.
**the problem**
When I leave the current ticket page to another ticket page the comment I created for the first ticket appear in the second ticket's page.

**the form**

```
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleAddComment} className="m-form">
                        <div className="group-control">
                            <textarea 
                                className="form-control" 
                                value={this.state.comment} 
                                name="comment"  
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                required
                            >
                            </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div className="m-widget13__action m--align-right">
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                                Add Comment
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

**Function add comment**

```
handleAddComment(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
        ticketId : this.props.complaintId,
        comment  : this.state.comment
    }
    // send create comment request
    this.props.complaintCommentCreate(data);
}
```

**After comment created I check received in component will receieve**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
{
    if(nextProps.createComment.comment)
    {
        // append created to comment to comments array
        this.setState({
            comments : this.state.comments.concat(nextProps.createComment.comment)
        })
        swal({ title: 'Success', type : "success", text: 'Comment created successfully!', timer: 3000});
    }
}
```

**After some tracking for solving the issue :** I found that componentWillReceiveProps method is still holding the data of the created comment instead of I changed the ticket page.

What should I do to handle this issue, please?

Comment: what is the result of `nextProps.createComment.comment` ? Also try that logic in `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: also what is `comments `, an array?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi
comments ===> array of comment related to ticket,
result of nextProps.createComment.comment ===> string

Comment: 1. instead of concat `push` to comments array. 2. it is not clear where in the code you clear the comment in the state. I recommend at the end of  `handleAddComment`  clear the state.  From the props (unless we see the whole structure)  it is hard to say if there is a problem with `willReceiveProps`. 
Also as mentioned `willRecieveProps` is unsafe officially and use `didUpdate` instead